# Elliptic curves and quasi-self-reciprocal polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, elliptic-curves

I am reading Shoichi Kihara's [*On the rank of the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+k$, II*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195510171) [Proc. Japan Acad. Ser. A Math. Sci. Volume 72, Number 10 (1996), 228-229].

In his paper Kihara considers the $1$-parameter family of elliptic curves or elliptic surface, $y^2=x^3+k(t)\;$ with

$k(t) = \frac{1}{4}(a(t)^6+b(t)^6+c(t)^6-2a(t)^3b(t)^3-2b(t)^3c(t)^3-2c(t)^3a(t)^3)\;$ and

$a(t), b(t), c(t) \in \mathbb{Q}(t).$

Kihara chooses $a(t) = 3t^3-49, b(t)=3t^3+16$ and $c(t)=39.$

Now he seems to exploit that this triple of $a,b$ and $c$ gives $k(t)$ with the property that

$k(t) = k(\frac{m}{t})\frac{t^{12}}{m^6}$ with $m=\frac{14}{3}$

whereby a new triple

$a'(t)=a(\frac{m}{t})\frac{t^2}{m}, b'(t)=b(\frac{m}{t})\frac{t^2}{m}$ and $c'(t)=c(\frac{m}{t})\frac{t^2}{m}$

resulting in the same $k(t)$ and the curve has six solutions with $x$-coordinates $ab$, $bc$, $ca$, $a'b'$, $b'c'$ and $c'a'$. Kihara uses $d,e$ and $f$ for $a',b'$ and $c'$

If it wasn't for the constant $m=\frac{14}{3}$ then $k(t)$ would be a self-reciprocal polynomial, hence the title of my question. The terminology quasi-self-reciprocal polynomial is mine.

Now, my questions are.

1) How could one anticipate the existence of $a,b$ and $c$ resulting in $k(t)$ with this property other than guessing? If one fixes $m=\frac{14}{3}$ in beforehand $a,b$ and $c$ can be found by brute force given the small coefficients, but I feel that one must know that they exist before searching.

2) Is there a general theory of these *quasi-self-reciprocal polynomials* that allows one to start with a different $m$ and find another triple $a,b$ and $c$ resulting in a different $k(t)$ with the same property?